# EXCEL - Creating conditionally format cells based on formatted cells in another sheets

Tags: excel, vba, format, cells

I have an Excel spreadsheet with 5 worksheets. The first worksheet is build like a mainmenu, which contains hyperlinks to the 4 other worksheets. The 4 other worksheets are containing conditionally formatted cells. Is it possible, to create conditionally formatted cells for each worksheet in the main menu / Sheet 1, which are getting red if something is formatted red in the specific worksheet? I've searched around the internet but no one has got a familiar problem, because I want to use more worksheets.

You can imagine it like this:

### Sheet 1 / Menu

```
       A                                      B
```

Link to Sheet 2 ------------------- Cell Lights up, if something is wrong in Sheet 2

Link to Sheet 3 ------------------- Cell Lights up, if something is wrong in Sheet 3

### Sheet 2

```
           A                           B
```

Cell Lights Up If Bigger Than B1 --------- Number

Cell Lights Up If Same Value like B2 ------ Text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pragmatically it is possible. If you are trying to implement it using the Excel front end features, Here is what i have tried and it worked for me. Check if it is any ways useful. I have crated a rule on Link2. If the Sheet2-A1 value is greater than 10, Link2 will highlight in red.
[image: Conditional format rule]

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks a lot! Solved my problem.